# Why is System.IO implemented this way

Tags: c#, path, directory, filepath, .net

Took me a while to find this bug in my code. Trying to create a temporary test directory:

```
Path.Combine("C:", "test"); 
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

So this *doesn't* create the directory `C:\test`. It seems to just create the directory `test` in the local folder of the executing assembly.

This is because `Path.Combine("C:", "test");` returns `C:test`, and not `C:\test`.

I don't pretend to know much about file systems so maybe the reason for this should be obvious, but I don't get it. I'm not sure why they implemented `Path` that way, or why `CreateDirectory` doesn't complain about an invalid directory name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you're combining a drive letter and a name. Under Windows that means "the name under the current directory of that drive". So for example:

```
C:\> cd foo
c:\foo> d:
d:\> mkdir c:bar
```

that would create `c:\foo\bar`. So it seems consistent with the design of Windows (harking back to MS-DOS) to me - that isn't necessarily a sensible design for Windows, but it makes sense for .NET to be consistent with it.

Comment: It's more the design of MS-DOS 2, 1982 or thereabouts.

Comment: Wow. How very odd. Well, that makes sense, in a "I had no idea you could do that" kinda way.

Answer (score 9):

`Path.Combine` behaves this way, because `:` is a valid [`VolumeSeparatorChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.volumeseparatorchar.aspx) - so a `\` doesn't get appended to `C:`.

From MSDN - [Path.Combine Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

> If path1 is not a drive reference (that is, "C:" or "D:") and does not end with a valid separator character as defined in DirectorySeparatorChar, AltDirectorySeparatorChar, or VolumeSeparatorChar, DirectorySeparatorChar is appended to path1 before concatenation.

As for the behavior of `CreateDirectory` - see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916012/why-is-system-io-implemented-this-way/7916062#7916062) by Jon Skeet.